# Is this sentence correct and complete?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct?

> Water is boiled until evaporates, and the steam circulates the
> turbine.

Do I need to add a pronoun before the verb "evaporate"?

> Water is boiled until **it** evaporates, ...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need “it” in that clause.

Also the sentence could probably be made more clear.

Perhaps something like

Water is heated until it evaporates. The steam creates pressure that causes the turbine to rotate.

If the device has more than one turbine, it should be turbines.

Another option: Water is heated until evaporation causes …